# Bridged adapter in Virtual Box - cannot obtain IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have virtual box with RHEL installed. My virtual box is running on windows 7 64 -bit. I configured bridged connection, but when I am restarting network interfaces, I receive following error:

```
Determining IP information for eth1... failed
```

On Windows XP it works without problems. I disabled Windows Firewall and installed latest Virtual Box, still without success.

NAT is working without any problems. What did I missed?

**UPDATE**

Ouput of `ifconfig -a` is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:B6:FC:69
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb6:fc69/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:36520 (35.6 KiB)  TX bytes:31455 (30.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:C3:84:4A
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec3:844a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:135419 (132.2 KiB)  TX bytes:4230 (4.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Output of `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Output of `dhclient -v eth1` is:

```
Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:c3:84:4a
Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:c3:84:4a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x6afb6c4c)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6afb6c4c)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x6afb6c4c)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x6afb6c4c)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x6afb6c4c)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Moreover the same machine with the same configuration works well on Windows XP. The problem is only on Windows 7.

Comment: Did you perhaps perform the installation on NAT? I know I've done that a few times and then had to reconfigure the network because the bridged adapter settings are different. I don't know 100% sure about Redhat but many distributions, especially those intended for servers, will set you up with a static IP to begin with.

Comment: How many adapters do you have? Why do you say: `when I restart networking`...? Do you mean to say it works when you start up the VM?

Comment: @Dylan with NAT everything is ok.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae No it doesn't. I tried to restart network service to see what is wrong.

Comment: Can you pls post the output of ifconfig -a ,  and of route -n, in the guest?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae added all outputs.

Comment: What is your antivirus / security suite ? I used to have an antivirus which was blocking VM network on the (legitimate) groud that a machine shouldn't emit packets pretending to come from another machine (i.e. the virtual one in this case). I had to tweak the configuration to allow networking to pass.

Comment: I apologize, I think I may have been unclear. I was not asking whether the NAT was okay, I know that - I was asking whether you perhaps had a static configuration specific to the NAT. I have this happen almost every time I set up a new VM, as I usually forget to start it in bridged mode and I'm usually setting up servers with static IPs. If the VM acquires it's IP address through DHCP, this won't be a problem, but if it's static (even partially) you'll need to reconfigure it. Can you post the output of, if I recall correctly, cat /etc/sysconfig/network (which I *hope* is correct for Redhat)?

Comment: Actually, it may be a file specific to the interface - /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth# (e.g. eth0)

Comment: @Offirmo how did you check what is blocking incoming packets?

Comment: @Dylan I have configuration for DHCP. Moreover as I wrote `dhclient -v eth1` doesn't connect at all

Comment: @Garath If you suspect a security software, you can 1) go into the software reports/logs to check if it is blocking packets 2) disable it entirely and have a try (do it in a safe network behind a firewall)

Comment: @Offirmo nothing found. Can I use Wireshark to debug this?

Comment: @Garath of course, outgoing packets (`ping www.google.com` is my favorite) should show up in Wireshark. However be sure to listen on the proper interface.

Comment: I found out that it is problem with my company DHCP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not with my machine, but my company DHCP server, which block more than one mac on port. It took me two days to find out that problem was "outside" my machine

Comment: In my case it was a corporate network devices configuration - they had to "whitelist" MAC of my virtual machine "somewhere in the network". Not sure where, but for sure it helped!