# Bridged connection for virtual machine is blocked by windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, vmware

I am trying to created virtual machine which in bridged mode. I already asked [Bridged adapter in Virtual Box - cannot obtain IP](https://superuser.com/questions/689131/bridged-adapter-in-virtual-box-cannot-obtain-ip) but it only assure me that problem is with my host machine. I also tired to install VmWare instead of VirtualBox and problem is exactly same.

So my question is: how can I diagnose what is blocking bridged mode on my Windows 7?

I already:

1. Disable Windows Firewall
2. I do not have any antyvirus software running

Answer (score 1):

The problem was somewhere which I did not suspect. It was on my company DHCP server which blocks more than one mac address on one port.